# How to get previous Fragment in Navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I use AndroidX Navigation to navigate Fragment in my app。

From A to B, and i want to get A in B, but i find there is no way to get A.

I try to get the backstack from FragmentManager, but the BackStackRecord's id is not useful.

Comment: Why not pass a value to B which identifies fragment A?

Comment: @IvanWooll Because I create a unique id in the fragment and will not change even the fragment recreated. And there almost every fragment need the previous fragment(args) to decide what anim style will be create.